# bootstrap menu show menu on hover instead of click

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to generate html horizontal menu

```
<div class="btn-group"">             
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle">About Us<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="/a/">Submenu 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="/b/">Submenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works on click, how can I rework this to change behaviour, to show submenu items menu on hover instead of click ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this css

```
.btn-group:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: this opens all submenu items, what if I have more than one main menu?

Comment: Give each menu a unique class class="dropdown-menu dd-about" also each button needs to be in a uniquely classed div like about-btn

Comment: Hey, this works for me with a little changes. Thanks. I have a problem, with hovering, clicking is still working, don't want click to work...only hover.